# Android: Adding a button on a status bar notification

Tags: android

I am trying to create a custom status bar notification in Android that has a button in addition to the text. The button can do a different thing than when you click the notification itself.
Is this possible at all? I'd also be ok putting an image of a button there instead. I know how to put an image, but not sure how to handle OnClick for an image embedded in RemoteViews. Your help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586938/clickable-custom-view-in-notification-on-android-2-3-or-lower

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can get a button on the status bar itself but you can certainly do it using a Custom Expanded View (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Ah. Thanks. That was actually what I meant. I am still not sure how to do it. It seems I have to use RemoteViews which doesn't have a member fun for adding a button. How do I set an OnClick for the button? Sorry if this is too newbish

Comment: There is setOnClickPendingIntent which should **in theory** allow you to trap a click on any object (including your button) but I don't seem to be able to get it to work in this application.

Has anyone had any success with this function?

Comment: I have the same problem.  I supply the button id as the viewID and the pendingIntent I wish to fire when the button is clicked, but nothing changes.  When any point in the notification view is clicked (including the button), the main pendingIntent, notification.contentIntent, is fired.

Comment: @Gallal, you need not setImageViewResource and setTextViewText for your RemoteViews. When they are set, the contentIntent and the button's PendingIntent will both get called.

Comment: @Gallal, have you found a solution to this?  Calling setOnClickPendintIntent with the button's id does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

try use this way,the first is the view ID,
the second is a Pending intent..

```
RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.push_notifi_content, Pdit);
```

I have try it,but seems it just support in android4.0

Comment: It is also possible in Android 2.3.4 (at least on my SGS2), I am using the Mp3-Player "PowerAMP" and it has several Buttons in its notification.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on this end as well. It is straightforward from HoneyComb onwards: look at the music app (it has a status bar control when playing). And you can implement yours with `your_notification_remote_view_instance.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.a_button_in_notification, pending_intent_to_be_handled_by_a_service);` while backing it with a service to handle the intent properly of course. While buttons can be embedded in earlier versions, they don't get focus or click when pressing.